# model predicts 0 values?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

Model creation using tensorflow it producess 0 output in the result?
  It never shows an output with -ve values. If the predict input tensor having -ve value it producess a +ve result. If the +ve input with -ve value as ys it having output 0

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
    var a=[[1,2,3,4]];
    const model = tf.sequential();
      const learninrate=0.1;
      const optimizer=tf.train.adam(learninrate);
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, inputShape: [7,3]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.compile({optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'meanSquaredError',metrics:['accuracy']});
    const xs = tf.tensor([[
      [11, 23, 1],
      [12, 23, 0],
      [13, 23, 0],
      [14, 23, 0],
      [15, 23, 0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]).toInt();
    const ys = tf.tensor([[[-12,-23,0],[-13,-23,0],[-14,-23,0],[-15,-23,0],[-11,-23,-1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]).toInt();
    console.log(xs);
    model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 1000}).then(()=>{
      model.predict(tf.tensor([[[15,23,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])).toInt().print();
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e);

    });
```

This is the model created in tensorflow js . Predicts only zero output in the result. why -ve in the ys is always producing zero result.How to handle this thing ?

output tensor is this in this model prediction

```
Tensor
    [[[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `npm` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: 1) your first layer is doing actually nothing without setting explicitly the activation (the default is `linear`, which is not useful for intermediate layers) 2) we never use a `relu` for the output layer (remove it, so that it becomes the default `linear`, suitable for regression 3) accuracy is meaningless in regression settings, like yours 4) too small model 5) too little data